# angular ui-grid cell template issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using angular `ui-grid` currently I am having all rows in which `qty` cell is editable by double clicking on it. I need to place input type text there and always editable, I am trying like this but when i I am submitting I am not getting values of this for post processes

```
 vm.gridColumnDefs = [
    {field: 'barcode', name: 'Barcode'},
    {field: 'productname', name: 'Product Name'},
    {field: 'categoryname', name: 'Category Name'},
    {field: 'suppliername', name: 'Supplier Name'},
    {field: 'sticks', name: 'sticks'},
    //{field: 'qty', name: 'quantity', enableCellEdit: true} // this is working fine
    {field: 'qty', name: 'quantity', type:'text', editableCellTemplate: '<input type="text" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-model="COL_FIELD" />'} 

  ];
```

Comment: can you post a working code snippet using plunker/codepen/jsfiddle etc? That would be helpful to debug your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ui-grid you will get field value in `row.entity.fieldname` in your case you will get qty field value in `row.entity.qty`. so,bind model like below code, you will get value of qty too. to show input box always use cellTemplate instead of editableCellTemplate.

```
vm.gridColumnDefs = [
    {field: 'barcode', name: 'Barcode'},
    {field: 'productname', name: 'Product Name'},
    {field: 'categoryname', name: 'Category Name'},
    {field: 'suppliername', name: 'Supplier Name'},
    {field: 'sticks', name: 'sticks'},
    //{field: 'qty', name: 'quantity', enableCellEdit: true} // this is working fine
    {field: 'qty', name: 'quantity', type:'text',enableCellEdit: true, cellTemplate: '<input type="text" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-model="row.entity.qty" />'} 

  ];
```

Comment: by default when loading first time or anytime, it is not showing cell as text type input, i have to double click on it make it text type

Comment: it's ok what is issue?

Comment: Actually I need to display input type=text when grid is loaded. I don't need to click on it make it textbox.